# Must declare the scalar variable "@VarName"

Tags: sql-server

Could anyone shed some light on this error for me? To a beginner of course. This will probably be no more than a simple fix for someone else. 
I'm trying to read in the Product to be used in the where clause.

```
alter proc Proc1
@ProductID int
as
go
select ProductName
from Products
where ProductID = @ProductID
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you to refer [@ThomasStringer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2241/thomas-stringer) 's answer - [GO After every T-SQL statement](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/59976/8783).

Answer (score 1):

Take out the `go` after the variable declaration.  It is causing SQL server to end the batch which makes your variable declaration go out of scope.

```
alter proc Proc1
@ProductID int
 as
 select ProductName
 from Products
 where ProductID = @ProductID
```

Here is some details from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) on what the `go` keyword/statement does.